# Hotkeys stop working after a few Process.Getprocess calls

Tags: c#, process, timer

I'm registering a hotkey with "RegisterHotKey" from user32.dll
Pressing the hotkey will trigger an event which does Console.WriteLine("HOTKEY");

Works great normally, but I am having a problem where after about 5 seconds it stops working. event is no longer triggered. 
By commenting things out, I have narrowed this down to 1 line of code:
Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
i.e. getting process names  (name doesn't matter, notepad or anything)

This GetProcessesByName is called on a System.Timers timer once per second. and like i said, after about 5 seconds (sometimes 3 or 4, its random) the hotkey stops working.

How can I fix this?

Below is the code i'm using ([from this website](http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207))

Could the problem have something to do with the 1st argument of RegisterHotKey??  (a HWND)
Must I have am active form to register hotkeys?

```
 public class HotkeyController {

    public HotkeyController() {
        KeyboardHook k = new KeyboardHook();
        k.RegisterHotKey(0, Keys.Subtract);
        k.KeyPressed += new EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs>(k_KeyPressed);
    }

    void k_KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("HOTKEY");
    }
}

public sealed class KeyboardHook : IDisposable {
    // Registers a hot key with Windows.
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);
    // Unregisters the hot key with Windows.
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the window that is used internally to get the messages.
    /// </summary>
    private class Window : NativeWindow, IDisposable {
        private static int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;

        public Window() {
            // create the handle for the window.
            this.CreateHandle(new CreateParams());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Overridden to get the notifications.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="m"></param>
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
            base.WndProc(ref m);

            // check if we got a hot key pressed.
            if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY) {
                // get the keys.
                Keys key = (Keys)(((int)m.LParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
                ModifierKeys modifier = (ModifierKeys)((int)m.LParam & 0xFFFF);

                // invoke the event to notify the parent.
                if (KeyPressed != null)
                    KeyPressed(this, new KeyPressedEventArgs(modifier, key));
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs> KeyPressed;

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose() {
            this.DestroyHandle();
        }

        #endregion
    }

    private Window _window = new Window();
    private int _currentId;

    public KeyboardHook() {
        // register the event of the inner native window.
        _window.KeyPressed += delegate(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs args) {
            if (KeyPressed != null)
                KeyPressed(this, args);
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers a hot key in the system.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modifier">The modifiers that are associated with the hot key.</param>
    /// <param name="key">The key itself that is associated with the hot key.</param>
    public void RegisterHotKey(ModifierKeys modifier, Keys key) {
        // increment the counter.
        _currentId = _currentId + 1;

        // register the hot key.
        if (!RegisterHotKey(_window.Handle, _currentId, (uint)modifier, (uint)key))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Couldn’t register the hot key.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A hot key has been pressed.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs> KeyPressed;

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose() {
        // unregister all the registered hot keys.
        for (int i = _currentId; i > 0; i--) {
            UnregisterHotKey(_window.Handle, i);
        }

        // dispose the inner native window.
        _window.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// Event Args for the event that is fired after the hot key has been pressed.
/// </summary>
public class KeyPressedEventArgs : EventArgs {
    private ModifierKeys _modifier;
    private Keys _key;

    internal KeyPressedEventArgs(ModifierKeys modifier, Keys key) {
        _modifier = modifier;
        _key = key;
    }

    public ModifierKeys Modifier {
        get { return _modifier; }
    }

    public Keys Key {
        get { return _key; }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The enumeration of possible modifiers.
/// </summary>
[Flags]
public enum ModifierKeys : uint {
    Alt = 1,
    Control = 2,
    Shift = 4,
    Win = 8
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code please? From what you're saying it sounds like your implementation is poor.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have added the code. its from this site: http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207

Answer (score 0):

thanks Alex, you gave me an idea to try this using a form (as i was using in the past) and its working fine now.

in the code i posted, it makes a Window like so (what is this and how is it different from a form?)
`private Window _window = new Window();`

perhaps `Process.GetProcesses` finds this "Window" and kills it? thus stopping the hotkeys from working?
who knows??   i am no guru...

anyway, i can just make an invisible form, which is good enough.

this is the "hotkey form" code i'm using:

```
public partial class HotkeyForm : Form {
    public HotkeyForm() {
        InitializeComponent();

        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 0, 0, (int)Keys.Subtract);


    }


    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0312) {
            switch (m.WParam.ToInt32()) {
                case 0: //numpad minus.
                    //Environment.Exit(0);
                    Console.WriteLine("FORM HOTKEY");
                    break;

            }

        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }


}
```